# GitHub not showing changes on pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have a branch that I want to merge into the `develop` branch, let's call it `feature-branch`. I've made changes to one file and opened a PR on GitHub. When viewing the PR, the diffing shows "0 files changed". Viewing the same file on the two respective branches in GitHub's built-in code editor shows the difference between the two branches, but in the PR it remains as "0 files changed".

When diffing the two branches locally with `git diff feature-branch..develop`, the change is shown. Both local branches are up to date with their remote counterparts, I've tried pulling them and resetting them to remote, but the issue remains - the diff is showing up locally but not on GitHub.

I've tried closing and opening the PR again, deleting `feature-branch` and pushing it again, and changing the base branch on the PR to a different one then back to `develop`, but the issue remains - still showing 0 changes. At this point I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

Edit: I've solved the issue by:

1. Making a new branch from `develop`
2. Copying over the changes made previously in said file
3. Opening a new PR from the new branch

The PR now shows the relevant changes, despite this new branch being identical to the previous one, at least in terms of the file's contents. I'm leaving the question open because I still don't understand how the original issue happened, but this is an okay workaround.

Comment: did you commit the changes in "feature"? did you push it?

Comment: @RenatoC.Francisco Yes. Doing a git commit returns "nothing to commit". Also, as I've mentioned, the change can be seen on Github's built-in browser editor, so the change has been committed and pushed to remote. Pushing also returns "Everything up-to-date"

Comment: Seems like a glitch to me. I don't think there's any way we could solve the mystery without poking around your repo. Is it public by any chance? If not, there's little point in keeping the question open.